# Justify in RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc, justify

I want to use justify feature in rdlc but it doesn't support. There have been algorithm writers in this problem, but when I get the output, I get results again (not justify).

I hope I can get a solution to this problem.
Thanks a lot ..

Comment: Can you share example of expected output and actual output? Also relevant code?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately RDLC is not as successful as the microsoft word.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. add this function to report propertise in tab Code:

   ```
   Function GetText(text As String, width As Integer) As String
        Dim palabras As String() = text.Split(" "c)
        Dim sb1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim sb2 As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim length As Integer = palabras.Length
        Dim resultado As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < length
            sb1.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras(i))
            If sb1.ToString().Length > width Then
                resultado.Add(sb2.ToString())
                sb1 = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                sb2 = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(i), i + 1)
            Else
                sb2.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras(i))
            End If
            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
        End While
        resultado.Add(sb2.ToString())

        Dim resultado2 As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)()
        Dim temp As String

        Dim index1 As Integer, index2 As Integer, salto As Integer
        Dim target As String
        Dim limite As Integer = resultado.Count     
        For Each item As String In resultado        
            target = " "
            temp = item.ToString().Trim()
            index1 = 0
            index2 = 0
            salto = 2

            If limite <= 1 Then
                resultado2.Add(temp)
                Exit For
            End If
            While temp.Length <= width
                If temp.IndexOf(target, index2) < 0 Then
                    index1 = 0
                    index2 = 0
                    target = target + " "
                    System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(salto), salto - 1)
                End If
                index1 = temp.IndexOf(target, index2)
                temp = temp.Insert(temp.IndexOf(target, index2), " ")

                index2 = index1 + salto
            End While
            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(limite), limite + 1)
            resultado2.Add(temp)
        Next

        Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each item As String In resultado2
            builder.Append(item).Append(chr(10))
       Next
        Return builder.ToString()
    End Function
   ```
2. Call custom code in yout textbox:

> ```
> =Code.GetText("longtext…",77)
> ```

i know you are using C# , but in rdlc you can write vb code only.

the VB code converted from C# in this original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235745/2713855

also you can use custom dll reference with C# code and then you need only to call the function in you textbox [Adding Custom Assemblies](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30555/Adding-Custom-Assemblies-in-SQL-Server-Reporting-S)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this code is not as successful as the microsoft word. The template is very important to me. So I will export the microsoft word and edit there. This time it does not fit on a single page in the word. I would like to thank microsoft's rdlc developers for not fixing this feature for years.
and moreover they do not publish good examples describing rdlc features.
Thank you !

Comment: yes, you are right ... there is not official justify support from Microsoft for RDLC reports