# Justify In SSRS Report Server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS Report Server 2017 Version. Is there any option to expect the result as same as "JUSTIFY" option in MS- Word?

Now, I am Exporting this SSRS Report into MS- Word.

I Need to Know Is there any Option to achieve the Same in while Rendering / Export the Report into MS- Word?

Thanks in advance.....

My Output:

[image]

Expected:

Need to aligned properly at Right Side (like a 'justify'in MS-Word)

[image]

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is not possible when exporting directly from SSRS to Word.

Comment: Is there any other options? @AlanSchofield

Comment: You could look at 3rd party renderers to see if something like ASPOSE Words For SSRS (https://products.aspose.com/words/reporting-services) offers this. Other than that you could look at applying a template manually or writing an external tool which fixes the formatting in the output file. Lots of ways to do it but none of them are straight forward as far as I am aware.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703964/justify-in-rdlc/62704667#62704667